# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have been sctatching my head with this one, I am usually a jQuery chap, however I have a Magento extension that uses prototype and am a bit lost on how to fix this error:

I am getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined` I am guessing because I need to check for the existence of certain HTML in the page in question (the javascript file appears on every page so might not have the relevant html every time.

Originally I was getting a `spConfig undefined` which is why I put in the `if ((typeof spConfig == 'undefined') || !spConfig) {` line

The original code is:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
if(spConfig.config.dynamics == 1 && spConfig.config.showbottom == 1){
    $$('.product-options-bottom')[0].insert({top: new Element('p', {id:'bottom-avail', class:'availability'}).update($$('p.availability')[0].innerHTML)});
    if(spConfig.config.showship == 1){
        $('bottom-avail').insert({after: new Element('p', {id:'bottom-shipsin', class:'shipsin'}).update($$('p.shipsin')[0].innerHTML)}); }
}
});
```

I tried changing to

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
if ((typeof spConfig == 'undefined') || !spConfig) {

} else {
    if(spConfig.config.dynamics == 1 && spConfig.config.showbottom == 1){
        if($$('p.availability') != 'undefined' ){
            $$('.product-options-bottom')[0].insert({top: new Element('p', {id:'bottom-avail', class:'availability'}).update($$('p.availability')[0].innerHTML)});
        }
        if(spConfig.config.showship == 1){
            if($$('p.shipsin') != 'undefined'){
                $('bottom-avail').insert({after: new Element('p', {id:'bottom-shipsin', class:'shipsin'}).update($$('p.shipsin')[0].innerHTML)}); 
            }
        }
}
}
});
```

However I still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined` pointing at line `$$('.product-options-bottom')[0].insert({top: new Element('p', {id:'bottom-avail', class:'availability'}).update($$('p.availability')[0].innerHTML)});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `$$()` method returns a list (or array) of elements that match the CSS selector you cant check if its `undefined` - but you can check the number of elements returned in the list.

so try this

```
if($$('p.availability').length != 0)
{
    $$('.product-options-bottom')[0].insert(
        {
            top: new Element('p', {id:'bottom-avail', 'class':'availability'}).update(
                $$('p.availability')[0].innerHTML
            )});
}
```

Also the `class` property in the `new Element()` should be in a string, as class is a keyword in certain browsers, also will become part of the core Javascript language in ECMA 6

Comment: Thanks for the class hint as well, that solved the next error I got once I put in the length check!